# How do I fix maven error The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly?

Tags: maven, inno-setup

**Issue:**

I am getting the Maven error "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" when I run through Inno setup batch execution. However, I am able to run successfully outside Inno Setup.(e.g Command line, Batch file, Vbs). I am clueless to identify the issue.

**Inno Setup Invoked Prompt:**

```
C:\>mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

**Regular Command Prompt:**

```
C:\>mvn -version
C:\
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**Maven Command from InnoSetup:**

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\@Setup\MavenInstaller.bat"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""{tmp}\MavenInstaller.bat"""
```

**Maven Command from Batch File:**

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mycomponent-DartifactId=%APPLICATION_NAME% -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

**Setting JAVA_HOME**

Check the If Java 1.8 is installed or not. If not installed, Install the same and set the JAVA HOME as follows.

```
SETX JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;" /f
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `SETX` command does not modify the current environment.

If you run the following batch file:

```
setx AAA aaa
echo AAA=%AAA%
```

It will print

```
AAA=
```

So your batch file is wrong. You have to use `set`:

```
set AAA=aaa
```

---

See [What is the difference between SETX and SET in environment variables in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/916649/213663).

Comment: You nailed it, I am able to echo the JAVA_HOME. Still maven command was not working. Let me work on it.

Answer (score 97):

Following is the best way to get of the issue , check following on classpath:

1. Make sure JAVA_HOME system variable must have till jdk e.g `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80` , don't append bin here.
2. Because MAVEN will look for jre which is under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`
3. Set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in classpath .

Then try Maven version .

Hope it will help .

Comment: This is the one which solved my problem too
Credit to @mukesh sharma

Comment: Regarding #3 I think you mean windows PATH variable, not classpath

Comment: I already have JAVA home configured without bin but still getting same error

Comment: can you please update answer also to linux

Answer (score 63):

My JDK is installed at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\`.
I had set `JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\`,
and I was getting this error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

When I changed the `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre`, the issue got fixed.
I am not sure how.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your answer to make the code parts more evident, and easier for Stack Overflow users to read - please see the editing help for more information on formatting.   Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is work, thank you. But how can this work using directory `jre` instead `bin`?

Comment: You might need to restart the bash/cmd for it to reflect changes.

Comment: This has worked for me as well. Since I installed the JDK via IntelliJ IDEA it saved it on `%HOMEPATH%\.jdks` so my path that I had to add to the environment variables ended up being `%HOMEPATH%\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322\jre`. Thanks : )

Comment: this solved it for me. not sure if it may impact other things relying on JAVA_HOME though

Answer (score 57):

This is how I fixed this issue on **Windows 10**:

My JDK is located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` and the problem I had was the space in `Program Files`. If I set **JAVA_HOME** using `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"` then Maven had an issue with the double quotes:

```
C:\Users>set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"

C:\Users>echo %JAVA_HOME%
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"

C:\Users>mvn -version
Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2""=="" was unexpected at this time.
```

Referring to `Program Files` as `PROGRA~1` didn't help either. The solution is using the **PROGRAMFILES** variable inside of JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Users>echo %PROGRAMFILES%
C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files>set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk-11.0.2

C:\Program Files>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2

C:\Program Files>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T17:06:16+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Comment: This perfectly that worked for me, thanks! +1

Comment: It works on a single project once the values are set inside it's directory. How do I make it work everywhere?

Comment: `setx JAVA_HOME "%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk-17.0.4" /M` this set the value permanently

Comment: thank you, I came to your answer twice now! Wish I could upvote twice!

Answer (score 19):

A very common mistake people make is that, when they set `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME`, they set the value to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin` or similar.

Please note `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` value should not contain `\bin`

Comment: This was my error. Removing \bin did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

removing JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE from environment variable is resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue while using **mvn clean package** command in Windows OS

```
C:\eclipse_workspace\my-sparkapp>mvn clean package
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I resolved this issue by deleting **JAVA_HOME** environment variables from *User Variables* / *System Variables* then restart the laptop, then set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable again.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: In my laptop at work it was enough to just changing the JAVA_HOME and closing and re-opening the console. But in my laptop at home I had not restart the laptop after changing the JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with the same issue, and the following worked for me.

Step 1: Check your JAVA_HOME setting. It may look something like:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"
```

Step 2: Update JAVA_HOME like so:

```
$ vim .bash_profile 

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile
```

Step 3: In a new shell, check that the Maven command is now working properly:

```
$ mvn -version
```

If this fixed the problem, you should get back a response like:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: I have this: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` but still get the error.

Answer (score 6):

Setting JAVA_HOME directory from command line worked for me!

First:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
```

Or :

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
```

Then try:

```
mvn -version
```

to make sure you do not get the same error. :)

Answer (score 5):

I have removed JAVA_HOME variable and kept only path and classpath variables by pointing them to jdk and jre respectively. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Windows 7.

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

The solution turned out to be very simple - right click on command prompt shortcut and choose "Run as Administrator". After that, the problem disappeared)

Answer (score 5):

In your environment variable path, add this

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

and also add your path of Maven folder like this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin
```

Then create user variable named

```
JAVA_HOME
```

and set as path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\
```

(wihout bin!)

Last step: *important*
Restart IntelliJ or another program you are using.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue while my JAVA_HOME system variable was pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin and my PATH entry consisted of just %JAVA_HOME%.

I changed my JAVA_HOME variable to exclude the bin folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171), and added the bin folder to the system PATH variable: %JAVA_HOME%\bin,

Answer (score 3):

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

worked fine for me.

Note - Don't put double quotes over the path as mentioned above. Otherwise when you run

```
mvn -version
```

it will give following error

> `Files\java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre""==""` was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 2):

when you setup the java home variable try to target path till JDK instead of java. setup path like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231

if you make path like  C:\Program Files\Java it will run java but it will not run maven.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `JAVA_HOME` from environment variables solved the issue for me.

Comment: At least three existing answers already say that.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps solved the issue for me..

- Copied the zip file into the Program Files folder and extracted to "apache-maven-3.6.3-bin".
- Then copied the path,
  ***C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3***
- Then created the new MAVEN_HOME variable within environmental variables with the above path.

Also added,

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin
```

address to the "PATH" variable

Answer (score 1):

1. create folder Maven  inside this folder extract download file
2. this file should  C:\Program Files\YourFolderName  must in C:\Program Files drive
3. goto This PC -> right click -> properties -> advanced system -> environment variable
4. user variable ----> new &
   ** note create two variable ** if not may be give error
   i)   variable name = MAVEN
   variable value = C:\Program Files\MAVEN

   ii)  variable name = MAVEN_HOME
   variable value = C:\Program Files\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.6.3\apache-maven-3.6.3
5. system variable
   path ---> Edit---> new----give path of this folder
   i) C:\Program Files\MAVEN
   ii) C:\Program Files\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin

Hurrraaaaayyyyy

Answer (score 1):

I have run the below command as Administrator to solve the issue:

```
SETX JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2"
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin;" /f
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easy Win10 solution**
After JDK installation, download maven and paste to C:/, then copy its path and paste to "environment variables".
Go to "windows key" on keyboard an type "environment variables". Click button "environment variables" on right-bottom corner.

From "system variables" choose JAVA_HOME and click "edit"
Probably you have path to Java JRE instead of JDK. Check where you install JDK (in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 ) and paste that path.

**REMEMBER!! JDK path should **not** be path to **bin** folder** because you will get **double bin** like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\bin\java because Maven check (see else condidion) :

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    JAVACMD=`which java`
else
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
 
if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
    echo "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" >&2
    echo "This environment variable is needed to run this program" >&2
    echo "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mac...

1. install JDK
2. config JAVA_HOME by `vim ~/.bash_profile` like this, change the jdk file path to your own

   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home
   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
   export JAVA_HOME PATH CLASSPATH
3. `source ~/.bash_profile` and then check by `java -version` and `mvn install`
4. if it does not work, restart your computer and check again.

i solved this problem by restarting my computer...

Answer (score 0):

In case of windows if there is any space in path to jdk like ("C:\Program Files\jdk") then it doesn't work, but if we keep jdk in a location which doesn't have space then it works fine like ("C:\jdk")

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Maven doesn't like the `JAVA_HOME` variable to have more than one value. In my case, the error was due to the presence of the additional path `C:\Program Files\Java\jax-rs` (the whole path was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20;C:\Program Files\Java\jax-rs`).

So I deleted the `JAVA_HOME` variable and re-created it again with the single value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with these steps:

1. Uninstall JDK java
2. Reinstall java, [download JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) installer
3. Add/Update the JAVA_HOME variable to JDK install folder

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to fix it:

My jdk location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

C:\Users>echo %PROGRAMFILES%
C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files>set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

C:\Program Files>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

C:\Program Files>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: E:\java\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin..
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the full path to the JDK folder. IF you use links like `~` in your path replace it with `/home/<your_user>/`, or it will give this error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add \bin when adding path

do

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

do not..

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin

Comment: That's what many existing answers say already.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME needs to be set where the jdk is present
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13
In the path you could use %JAVA_HOME%/bin

PS : Also check if you are pointing to the right version of jdk in your environment variables.
In my case I had jdk-11.0.13 but had outdated path in the env variable which was still pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301.

Answer (score 0):

You can set JAVA HOME by following commands in CMD

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

Make sure to close all CMD instances and then open them again to check.

Answer (score 0):

also, sometimes it might cause some problems if the java_home variable is not included in the user variables for administrators' section. So also add them there if you are logged into the administrators account.

as you know, java home var should not have the bin part while the path should point to the bin.

Answer (score 0):

## Linux Users

For Linux users, export the path to the base of the installation directory of your JDK.

For example

```
export PATH=/data/gadgets/opt/java/openjdk/current/bin/:$PATH
```

Please note that this is **not** the typical location on most Linux systems. **However, you can find the location by searching for `javac`:**

```
find / -type f -name 'javac' 2>/dev/null
```

which will print a list of filenames matching `javac`. There will likely be only one, but there can be more than one if you have multiple JDKs installed.

Answer (score -1):

add following on env path:

1. Make sure JAVA_HOME system variable e.g
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk , don't append bin here.
2. Restart your computer

Comment: At least three existing answers already say that.

Answer (score -5):

Also Please make sure your java, mvn and all installations are in C Directory

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: The information is incorrect.
Maven or Java are drive agnostic on Windows, they do not depend on installation folder to be on a specific drive.